# Using sed to extract an email address

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to become familiar with `sed` by extracting email address from input in the following form:

`something_from.someone:user@email.com`

That is the input I'm sending to `sed`, I'm trying to remove everything up to and including `:`:

```
sed 'd/[[alphanum:]]+[.][[:alphanum:]]+[:]//'
```

Based on my research, this should do it, but I'm getting this error:

`sed: 1: "d/[[:alphanum:]]+[.][[: ...": extra characters at the end of d command`

Any ideas as to what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Using Regular Expressions is probably the best way. This regex match 99.99% of email adress :

    /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

Comment: @Alban Thank you!  But my question isn't really with regards to the email address.  I'm trying to understand how to use `sed` and also understand why my command above isn't working.

Comment: This makes it in sed: `sed 's/.*:\(.\)/\1/g'`. I don't have enough knowledge of the language to point out what is bad on your code.

Comment: @fedorqui what does `\(.\)` do?  I understand the escaping portion and the `\1/g'` but that one piece is the only confusing part for me

Comment: It gets all the text, @code4me.

Comment: @fedorqui, no need to capture and replace in this case, just remove the matched text: `sed 's/.*://'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your delete syntax is incorrect. To delete in sed you need to do:

```
sed '(separator) [pattern to delete](separator)d'
```

Thus, for example:

```
sed -e '/regex/d' infile
```

This is for deleting whole lines generally. What you want to do instead is keep some part of the line so you need a capture-and-replace:

```
sed -e  's/regex-to-drop\(regex-to-keep\)/\1/g' input-file
```

The 's' is for substitute and the 'g' is for global, and the `\( \)` is what is captured while the `\1` is where I want the captured thing to go. If I had a series of captured items,

```
\(something\)\(something_else\)
```

I could reproduce them with another character between them by simply putting the following in the substitute part of the sed command:

```
\1 ;; \2
```

This would produce: `something ;; something_else` and altogether would look like:

```
sed -e 's/\(something\)\(something_else\)/\1 ;; \2/g' input-file
```

In your case, it looks like you want to drop everything before the colon:

```
sed -e 's/^.*:\(.*\)$/\1/g' input-file
```

---

**Footnote** to the above as suggested by @fedorqui:

Sed uses standard regex notation to refer to the beginning and end of a line, so "^" refers to the beginning of the line and "$" refers to the end of the line. Thus, the complete explanation of the above is as follows:

```
's/^.*:
```

Everything from the start of the line up to the colon (the "s" means we're setting up a 'substitute' command).

Then:

```
\(.*\)$/
```

CAPTURE everything up to the end of the line, and

```
/\1/g'
```

Substitute the WHOLE line with the captured item. Do it globally (for the whole file).

Comment: Can you use `[[:alphanum:]]` etc in `sed`?

Comment: Yes, but it looks like `[:alpha:]`, `[:alnum:]`, and `[:digit:]`.

Comment: This is a terrific explanation, congrats. I would add the fact that `^` refers to the beginning of the line, while `$` to the end of it. Hence, `^.*:\(.*\)$` means `something up to : and then the rest saved in \1`.

Comment: Thanks. I will add that in so anyone who discovers this can understand what every character means.

Comment: Just an FYI:  cut might be more applicable than sed, since this problem basically involves extracting one field from a series of delimited fields (in this case the colon being the delimiting character).  This command will do the job:  `echo something_from.someone:user@email.com | cut -d: -f1`  in the cut command, the -d: specifies that : is the delimiter.  -f1 means output field 1 (the fields are indexed starting from zero).

Comment: I totally agree that there are better tools for the job than sed. My first thought was to do a lookbehind but then I remembered that you can't do those in sed.

Comment: @mti2935 note that the issue itself is that the OP wants to learn how to do this in `sed`, as wants to get familiar with it. `cut`, `awk`, `grep` can also make it (even easier) but the OP wants it this way.

Comment: That's exactly why I didn't bother offering any other ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is far from being perfect, but works somehow:

```
echo "something_from.someone:user@email.com" |  sed  -rn "s/.*[ <=;,:]([^@ <>\"\{\}:+]*@[^@ \"]*\.[^@ <>\",;=)]*)[ >=;,:\)]?.*/\1/gp" # output: user@email.com
```

The logic:

```
[separators]([name]@[domain234].[domain1])[separators] ... print (email)
```

For instance I do not know how to get rid of these brackets [] in email. "\]" does not work.

I beg those smarter me to improve. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my stab at it using my own example:

```
EMail="#E-mail: Andrew.Meyer@edu.gov.ca #testing parsing"
echo $EMail |  sed  -E "s/.*[^a-zA-Z0-9._]([a-zA-Z0-9._]*@[a-zA-Z0-9._]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9._]*)[^a-zA-Z0-9._]?.*/\1/"
```

Here is an explanation of the parts:

`sed -E` : Extended regular expressions (can also use -r) -E is POSIX compliant

`s/.*[^a-zA-Z0-9._]` - Start of by excluding `^` any non-valid e-mail address components

`([a-zA-Z0-9._]*@` - Match any valid e-mail characters directly preceeding an `@` symbol

`[a-zA-Z0-9._]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9.*]*)` - Match a set of valid e-mail characters after the `@` with at least one "." in the set. Denoted by the `*\.` in the middle. The entire matching pattern is enclosed in the `()`

`[^a-zA-Z0-9._]?.*/\1/"` - Exclude, using the `^`, any non-valid trailing e-mail address characters on the end if there are any and display the 1st matching pattern using the `\1`

The entire sed entry is bound by the `"s/ ... /"`